# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.coremedia.iso.boxes.mdat.MediaDataBox

Tags: java

can anybody help in solving the title exception? (run in cmd of win7, Java jre7)
some examples for the detailed exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.coremedia.iso.boxes.mdat.MediaDataBox
        at com.coremedia.iso.PropertyBoxParserImpl.createBox(PropertyBoxParserImpl.java:112)
        at com.coremedia.iso.AbstractBoxParser.parseBox(AbstractBoxParser.java:102)
        at com.googlecode.mp4parser.BasicContainer.next(BasicContainer.java:155)
.....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.coremedia.iso.boxes.mdat.MediaDataBox
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The class you are trying to execute is not found. compile and run again

Comment: The class `com.coremedia.iso.boxes.mdat.MediaDataBox` is not present at the classpath. As a hint look up the meaning of the [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) and how to set and use it.

Comment: A snippet of your code could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs,ClassNotFoundException is thrown when:

```
Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:

    * The forName method in class Class.
    * The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader.
    * The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.

but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line shows up a class loader (URLClassLoader) that tries to load a class "com.coremedia.iso.boxes.mdat.MediaDataBox" which is not accessible.

I guess there is a dependency missing; check your project setup.

According to google the class tried to be loaded belongs to a mp4Parser component.
Check if this and all needed dependencies are available on your class path.